# IntelliJ showing source and test files in same package

Tags: intellij-idea, package-explorer

I am using  `IntelliJ 2011.1.1 CE` and now suddenly it start showing source (`.java`) and test classed in same package.
I have selected "**packages**" view which is used to show only `src` files

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Packages view has always shown both test and production classes.

If test and production files are located in different modules you can enable  **Show Modules** option to separate them:
[image]

It also shows test files with different background colors, which you can configure in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | File Colors | Appearance & Behavior | **File Colors**.

A related request: *[IDEA-144965](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144965) Add option to hide test files in the 'Packages' of 'Project' tool window*

Comment: I am not sure if there were some customisation in my IntelliJ, but is was just showing `src` classes and not `test classes` when `packages` mode is selected.